# City / State Combination Verifier? (Exp:resso Store)

Tags: expresso-store

Any ideas on implementing a city/state combination check before order submission? Client has a few orders with cities and zip codes that don't exist in the state they submitted. Example: Atlanta, NY, 30346.

My first step was to ensure that all fields were clearly labeled and conspicuous.

Unfortunately an order came in last week with a city/state mismatch. It may have something to do with my client's userbase.

Any ideas? Pretty sure it will involve an extension using the store_order_submit_start hook and a rather large database, but that's all I have right now.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Bobby

Answer (score 3):

You would need to either write an extension as you have suggested or there are some javascript libraries available too. In the past I have used am API called [Ziptastic](http://daspecster.github.io/ziptastic/index.html)
which requires that the user enters their zip code then it will find the matching city/state/country for the particular address. The times that I have used it the only required shipping requirements were in the US so I can not speak for how it works for international shipping but it is a start instead of trying to manage your own DB of addresses.